# PDF Viewer flutter packages is not installing pdf_flutter any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed

Tags: flutter

I want to install pdf viewer packages but its not installing and gives me error "Because desktop_app depends on pdf_flutter any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.".
I tried alternate option also but all padf viewer packages give me same error.

I am creating desktop support app.

I am using latest flutter version, please find **flutter doctor**.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1702], locale en-GB)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources
```

**Flutter upgrade**

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.10.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 682aa387cf (3 days ago) • 2023-06-05 18:04:56 -0500
Engine • revision 2a3401c9bb
Tools • Dart 3.0.3 • DevTools 2.23.1
```

What is the solution of this error? how I can use flutter pdfviewr in flutter?